# Why do I get "Do you want to submit the form again" even after redirect?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a strange issue here - see below.

Page X

- Contain a form having method as post
- User submits the form - There some form validation.
- If everything validates I save the data, set a flash data message in the session (i.e. query success/failed) and redirect() the user to current_ur()
- Now, I can see the flash message and If I press <kbd>F5</kbd> - I get do you want to submit the form again?

Shouldn't this just refresh the page? How do I stop it making another submit request?
If I redirect to Page Y, and press <kbd>F5</kbd> there, then it doesn't ask me to resubmit? I am lost here!

Comment: How are you performing the redirect? Are you sure you aren't just performing an *internal* redirect to a CodeIgniter route instead of a real HTTP redirect? Can you see the redirect in the HTTP traffic (which you can monitor with tools such as Charles Proxy)?

Comment: @Matt there is redirect() after that as well. I'm using redirect() function of CI. So I post the data, save it redirect it back to the same URL. Makes sense?

Comment: Got it. I'll remove my comment as it might be misleading. Also it's incorrect.

Comment: In chrome dev tools, go to network tab, clear all requests and activate recording. Then post the form. What do you see?

Comment: @Quentin - I'm using redirect('PAGE_URL') of CI - what is internal redirect?

Comment: @Esailija - where to see? - I just tried what you said

Comment: @user1421214 if you just did what I said the network tab should show all network activity as you submit the form [like this](http://i.imgur.com/X2hyO.png). Did you have recording on?

Comment: @Esailija Yes I can see the requests to images, stylesheets etc all are GET, then there is a POST and then GET again

Comment: Oh, and Chrome doesn't ask me resubmit on re-fresh. Seems like Firefox only issue. Just going to check IE and Safari.

Comment: @user1421214 Try with `header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other'); header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); exit;` instead of `redirect('PAGE_URL');`

Comment: @DaveRandom it seems to be an issue with Firefox only. See my answer below,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys

This is NOT a `CodeIgniter` issue. It is an issue with `Firefox`. I'm using `14.0.1` version of `Firefox`.

I have tried the same form and process in `IE 7, 8, 9`, `Safari 5,` `Chrome` (latest) - they don't show me the confirmation dialog box to re-submit the form on `F5`.

---

**Update**

In firefox I get this message -

> To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat
>   any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed
>   earlier.

I just setup another script (without CI) and tested in Firefox. I tried to create the similar process (i.e. post and redirect to same page) ... I don't get this message at all. Refresh works just fine. **So I take Its back on to CI now?**

**Update 2**

OK I think I have cracked it now -

I'm using CI's redirect function - see below - the second parameter takes default value as 'auto' and when it's `auto` it sends header as `header('Refresh:0;url='.$uri);` which makes the Firefox throw the above message. As mentioned above, I don't get the same behaviour in other browsers. I hope it helps someone.

```
function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $http_response_code = 302)
{
    if ( ! preg_match('#^https?://#i', $uri))
    {
        $uri = site_url($uri);
    }

    // IIS environment likely? Use 'refresh' for better compatibility
    if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR !== '/' && $method === 'auto')
    {
        $method = 'refresh';
    }

    switch($method)
    {
        case 'refresh':
            header('Refresh:0;url='.$uri);
            break;
        default:
            header('Location: '.$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
            break;
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Possible that CI is mistakenly issuing a 307 code? Other than that, it would seem to be an FF bug if that's the case (and an everywhere-else bug if it's not).

Comment: @DaveRandom - no it's not 307 - the 'culprit' is `header('Refresh:0;url='.$uri);` - I tried the same header in plain php script as I mentioned above and it makes the FF show confirmation dialog.

Comment: Right, there's your problem. `Refresh:` is a non-standard header. This cannot be considered a bug, because no official document defines the expected behaviour. Redirects should use a `Location:` header, and POST/Redirect/GET mechanisms should use a `303` response code. The code I mentioned in my comment on the question is the correct, RFC compliant way to do it.